# `nixos-rebuild switch` fails with "No space left on device"

Tags: disk-space-utilization, nixos

I keep filling up `/boot` with old kernels, at which point `nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade` will download a bunch of derivations only to eventually fail when installing the new kernel (or initrd) because there is insufficient space on `/boot`.

One option is to run `nix-collect-garbage -d`, but that can be extremely slow and can result in needing to download the newly downloaded versions all over again.

Sometimes deleting old kernels seems to help (until `/boot` fills up again), whereas other times, manually picking a few generations to delete from `ls /nix/var/nix/profiles/system-??-link` has worked better.

Is there a better approach to deal with `/boot` filling up? (Particularly for when I want to upgrade and use the new system right away.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a longstanding [bug report](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/23926) about this problem when `/boot` fills up. The situation has improved, but reading through all the comments takes a while, so I will attempt to summarize.

**If you are using GRUB**, set `boot.loader.grub.configurationLimit = 42;` (or pick a better number depending on how much space you have in `/boot`) so that older kernels will be automatically cleaned up. The existing old kernels will be cleaned up on the next `nixos-rebuild switch`, though you may need to manually delete some first, since the [install-grub.pl](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/93470276f953d162d53d2594927884fce17ff0a6/nixos/modules/system/boot/loader/grub/install-grub.pl) script will first attempt to copy the new kernels before deleting old ones.

**If you are using systemd-boot** (formerly Gummiboot), as of NixOS 19.03 ([thanks domenkozar](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/63766)), set `boot.loader.systemd-boot.configurationLimit = 42;` (or pick a suitable number depending on how much space you have in `/boot`), and the next `nixos-rebuild switch` should automatically clean up old kernels.

Note that you will want to run `nix-collect-garbage` eventually, before (or when) `/nix` fills up. This can also be set to run automatically by setting `nix.gc.automatic = true` [and related options](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#nix.gc).